# How activate translations (i18n) Activation in AEM

Tags: translation, aem

I have defined my translations under /apps/myProject/i18n using CQ5 Translator in author instance. I'm able to see the translation in author instance. But I'm unable to replicate the translations in publisher instance.

I would like to know the process of activating these translations to a publisher instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon activating the JCR node /apps/myProject/i18n from author using  http://{SERVER}:{PORT}/etc/replication/treeactivation.html, the translations will be seen in publisher instance.

Resource: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/components/i18n/translator.html